# MonoTouch WCF Service Reference.cs Errors

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios

I have a very simple WCF Service it has a single method GetDateTime(), I have it hosted in IIS on Windows 7, all seems to working fine in the windows environment, I can execute using test client application.

On my Mac using MonoTouch I have added a web reference to the Service, it finds the service and generates a whole lot of files.

When I compile the Mono project there is an error in the Reference.cs file that has been generated.

The GetDateTime Method in the interface has been declared with a return type GetDateTimeResponse instead of System.DateTime.

Any idea what has gone wrong is this a bug or have I missed something?

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="LastPrice.win7pro")]
public interface ITest {

    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://win7pro/ITest/GetDateTime", ReplyAction="http://win7pro/ITest/GetDateTimeResponse")]
    GetDateTimeResponse GetDateTime(GetDateTime GetDateTime);

    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://win7pro/ITest/GetDateTime", ReplyAction="http://win7pro/ITest/GetDateTimeResponse", AsyncPattern=true)]
    System.IAsyncResult BeginGetDateTime(GetDateTime GetDateTime, System.AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object userState);

    GetDateTimeResponse EndGetDateTime(System.IAsyncResult result);
}
```

Comment: How did you generate the Reference.cs file for this service?  The menus in MonoDevelop or SlSvcUtil.exe? http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_Web_Services

Comment: I used the Add Web Reference menu in Mono Develop

Comment: You might want to use `SlSvcUtil.exe` and see if it generates different code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Mono's WSDL generation.

I created a simple [test case](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/tree/master/TestWCF) for this, using Visual Studio 2012 Web Express, and it is working fine when copying the Reference.cs file from the Windows machine.

This is now fixed in [mono/master commit aa2e9ec](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/aa2e9eca4054e3756220c6c842894102d3e3e87b).

The bug affects all parameterless service methods with complex return types.

As a temporary workaround, use `SlSvcUtil.exe` on Windows to create the client proxy or add a dummy parameter to your service method.